# Can I use catch(e if e instanceof SyntaxError) in Node.js's javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch, try-catch-finally

I read about try catch(e if e instanceof ...) blocks on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch), however, upon trying it in Node.js, I get a SyntaxError: Unexpected token if.

If this doesn't work, is there another way to catch specific exceptions, instead of everything that might occur?

Comment: not sure, but you could catch it and rethrow it after inspecting it.

Comment: related: [Conditional catch clauses - browsers support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20483597/1048572)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To cite the MDN doc you linked to:

> Note: This functionality is not part of the ECMAScript specification.

and

> JavaScript 1.5, NES 6.0: Added multiple catch clauses (Netscape extension).

so: No, this won't be possible in Node.js. Yet, of course you can use the following syntax as a workaround:

```
try {
    try_statements
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof ...)
        catch_statements_1
    else if (e instanceof ...)
        catch_statements_2
    else
        throw e;
} [finally {
    finally_statements
}]
```

Comment: Appreciate the MDN citation ... totally missed that part when reading the documentation, works well now.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but does anyone know why this feature is neither standard nor being standardized ?
It could be great !

Comment: @UgoEvola It didn't make it into ES5, and interest since then has waned, probably because it's so easy to workaround with a little boilerplate. [The pattern matching proposal explores new ways to do this](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pattern-matching#integration-with-catch).