# Conditional catch clauses - browsers support

Tags: javascript, exception

What browsers support **Conditional catch clauses**?

On MDN [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) you can find [Conditional catch clauses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#Conditional_catch_clauses) as *Non-standard feature*.

```
try {
    myroutine(); // may throw three exceptions
} catch (e if e instanceof TypeError) {
    // statements to handle TypeError exceptions
} catch (e if e instanceof RangeError) {
    // statements to handle RangeError exceptions
} catch (e if e instanceof EvalError) {
    // statements to handle EvalError exceptions
} catch (e) {
    // statements to handle any unspecified exceptions
    logMyErrors(e); // pass exception object to error handler
}
```

> Note: This functionality is not part of the ECMAScript specification.

It's supported by any modern browsers?

Google Chrome's console returned `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if`

Or shoud I use:

```
try {
    myroutine(); // may throw three exceptions
} catch (e) {
    if(e instanceof TypeError) {
        // statements to handle TypeError exceptions
    }
    else if(e instanceof RangeError) {
        // statements to handle RangeError exceptions
    }
    else if(e instanceof EvalError) {
        // statements to handle EvalError exceptions
    }
    else {
        // statements to handle any unspecified exceptions
        logMyErrors(e); // pass exception object to error handler
    }
}
```

Comment: MDN is a JavaScript reference. And by JavaScript, I meant Mozilla's implementation and superset of ECMAScript. So you'll find that functionality in Firefox. No other major browser uses Mozilla's implementation as far as I'm aware. *(Well, there's IceWeasel, but that's basically the royalty free version of Firefox AFAIK.)*

Comment: Why not just try it in the browsers you care about?

Comment: Use the second way, it's just as readable and not much more code. The real question is why is your function throwing EvalErrors? Smells.

Comment: @Pointy - as you can see in my question, I already tried in chrome but its returned error so I would know there is just firefox its support or not

Answer (score 5):

You should use the later one, as it works everywhere, quoting MDN

> And here is how to do implement the same "Conditional catch clauses"
>   using only simple JavaScript conforming to the ECMAScript
>   specification (**obviously it's more verbose, but works everywhere (I have tested on Firefox, IE and Chrome)**), I have :

```
try {
    myroutine(); // may throw three types of exceptions
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof TypeError) {
        // statements to handle TypeError exceptions
    } else if (e instanceof RangeError) {
        // statements to handle RangeError exceptions
    } else if (e instanceof EvalError) {
        // statements to handle EvalError exceptions
    } else {
       // statements to handle any unspecified exceptions
       logMyErrors(e); // pass exception object to error handler
    }
}
```

The first one `catch (e if e instanceof ..)` only works with Mozilla Firefox and **gives errors on chrome and IE**

**Chrome**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if
```

**IE**

```
SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'
```

Answer (score 4):

> On MDN try...catch you can find Conditional catch clauses as Non-standard feature.
>
> Note: This functionality is not part of the ECMAScript specification.

What this means is that this is not part of the javascript language that all browsers and stuff have agreed upon having available. Which most certainly will mean that not all browsers will support it **if any**. Your best option regarding a cross-browser solution would be the second case using a switch clause. `GL`

Answer (score 4):

The link you mentioned in Question clearly states that it is **Non-standard.**
That is this code is experimental and not a part of **ECMA Specification.**

This works only in Moz because it's their idea and still not completely implemented.

For a thing to become a part of ECMA Specification, it needs lots of steps.

First Moz build it and then propose it and then only it will be accepted.

Till that moment, you can't use it in all websites.

Answer (score 2):

Only moz supports it. Everyone wishes every browser supported it. This effectively means you can't use it at all.